# Node.js Printing input letter by letter

Tags: node.js

I have tried to build a chat server using node.js however it prints the input on other clients' consoles letter by letter, is there a way to keep it all together

```
var net = require('net')

var chatServer= net.createServer()
clientList = []

chatServer.on('connection', function(client){
client.name = client.remoteAddress + ":" + client.remotePort
client.write('Hi' + client.name + "!\n");

clientList.push(client)

client.on('data', function(data){
    broadcast(data, client)
})
})

function broadcast(message, client){
for(var i=0; i<clientList.length;i+=1){
    if(client !== clientList[i]){
        clientList[i].write(client.name + " says" + message +"\n")
    }
}
}

chatServer.listen(9000, "127.0.0.1")
```

Thanks.

Comment: I guess you need to commit the data to the socket server only when a message has been fully typed.Since you didnt show what the code is in the client I cant help you.

Comment: The whole code is this. I run it over CMD using telnet. This runs on localhost. I connect 2 users over cmd by
    telnet 127.0.0.1 9000

Comment: if you connect users via telnet, nodejs cant guess where a message starts or stops.

Comment: oh ok. Thanks a lot. What is a good way to connect the users than ?

Comment: check the telnet doc to find out which character terminates a message and use it to find out when a message ends in node so you can commit it to other clients.

Comment: Ok I will thanks a lot ! In the worst scenario, I can add a if statement that would post on enter key otherwise append every key to a var. Thanks again !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this if your messages are newline-delimited:

```
chatServer.on('connection', function(client) {
  client.name = client.remoteAddress + ":" + client.remotePort;
  client.write('Hi' + client.name + "!\n");

  clientList.push(client)

  var buf = '';
  client.setEncoding('utf8');
  client.on('data', function(data) {
    buf += data;
    var i;
    while ((i = buf.indexOf('\n')) > -1) {
      broadcast(buf.substring(0, i), client);
      buf = buf.substring(i + 1);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man this works. Sorry I can not vote up, I dont have enough reputation yet :P